# Linux shell script for loop error

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to create a for loop to delete log files older than 15 days.  Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
path="/home/test"

logpath="$path/logs"
for logfile in `find $logpath -mtime +14 -type f -name *.log`
do
    echo "Deleting Log File: " $logfile
    rm -rf $logfile
done
```

It keeps throwing an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting $logpath before *.log ?

Comment: Try wrapping `*.log` within double-quotes like `"*.log"`

Comment: How do you execute the script? It's working fine for me when executing it like './test.sh'

Comment: i execute using crontab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this - added single quotes

```
#!/bin/sh
path="/home/test"

logpath="$path/logs"
for logfile in `find $logpath -mtime +14 -type f -name '*.log'`
do
    echo "Deleting Log File: " $logfile
    rm -rf $logfile
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `exec` param of `find` to get rid of the for loop:

```
find $logpath -mtime +14 -type f -name '*.log' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or like @Patryk Obara says :

```
find $logpath -mtime +14 -type f -name '*.log' -delete
```

which enable `-depth` implicitly.

You can test it like this :

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch test1.log
touch test2.log
find . -type f -name '*.log'
ls
> test1.log  test2.log
find . -type f -name '*.log' -delete
> empty
```

Comment: Or even better, `find` has shortcut for that, you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -rf {} \;`.

Comment: This is incorrect and obviously wasn't tested. You have the same issue as OP: you must escape the `*` in the `-name` with single quotes. `-name '*.log'`...

Comment: @smassey I added a script that works. Could you explain why you think single quotes would help ?

Comment: @Till If you don't quote the argument, the shell expands it immediately to the files that match in the current directory. Maybe it worked for you because you have no `*.log` files in your current directory.

Comment: @Till did you just "fake" the output of your script? `smassey@hacklabs:/tmp/test $ find ./ -type f -name *log`
 `find: paths must precede expression: test1.log` is what you would actually see.

Comment: @smassey No I did not fake it. I'm on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: Maybe it's bash vs sh. What do you have if you do `echo $0` ? I have "bash"

Comment: `smassey@hacklabs:/tmp/test $ echo $SHELL` 
`/bin/bash` .. very strange indeed. I just tried with `sh`, and get the same error as expected. The only way the above works if is expansion does not happen. There's only one case that comes to mind where this won't fail: the expansion missed because there are no .log files in your current directory, only in children directories. In this case the wildcard star is passed along as a string. If, on the other hand, you're in a directory where the match is made and expansion happens then the `find` command fails, exactly as shown in your example. Run it?

Comment: I edited my answer. I'll look again at the problem to see in which condition it fails/works.

Answer (score 0):

Logrotate is a better choice for this kind of job, here's a link to it's documentation - 
http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html